# how to pass local html files using array in xcode

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

here i am trying for a application,
when i click on the table view it will redirect to another page called details. there I have used a webview to dispaly the selected url value.
here is my code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    self.navigationItem.title=@"sample";
    servicesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [servicesArray addObject:@"1"];
    [servicesArray addObject:@"2"];
    [servicesArray addObject:@"3"];

    urlsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [urlsArray addObject:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [urlsArray addObject:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    [urlsArray addObject:@"http://www.facebook.com"];


}
```

here instead of urls link i want to pass my local html files. can you please help me out

Thanks
chintu.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,take all the html file names in Array yourArray.

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[yourArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[WebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: 4errors
Expected ':' at end of declaration
Missing '[' at start of message send expression
Use of undeclared identifier 'htmlArray'